# Order of function calls for mysqli prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

The php manual seems to be a little light regarding the mysqli extension and I am not finding any information poking with Google.

When I create a mysqli prepared statement, should the order of calls be

```
mysqli::prepare()
mysqli::stmt::bind_param()
mysqli::stmt::execute()
mysqli::stmt::store_result()
mysqli::stmt::bind_result()
```

or

```
mysqli::prepare()
mysqli::stmt::bind_param()
mysqli::stmt::execute()
mysqli::stmt::bind_result()
mysqli::stmt::store_result()
```

Furthermore, if I then want to change the parameters and reexecute the statement, should I use

```
mysqli::free_result()
mysqli::stmt::execute()
mysqli::stmt::store_result()
mysqli::bind_result()
```

or can I simply use execute() again and then use free_result() once I am finished using the statement?

Comment: I have tried just running the functions in both orders and, no surprise, on my test server any order works, but on my production server, one order works sometimes and then the other order works sometimes, but this changes over time.

Comment: If you have some problems with certain code, it's better to ask a question regarding this certain code, providing it along with question as well. However, I have a feeling that it's not call order but lack of error reporting being a cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not PHP manual but mysqli extension itself being unclear and ambiguous.

However, to clear your confusion

1. You can call `store_result()` anywhere you wish between prepare() and `fetch()`. As a matter of fact, `bind_result()` is just a supplementary function for `fetch()`.
2. In PHP you rarely need to free anything in general, and especially in cases like this, when result going to be overwritten in the next call. So - yes, you can simply call `execute()` again (with `bind_param()` first).

Also note that some installations will let you call [get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) which makes all that process with fetching variables at least sensible. But is isn't always available

Also note that neither `bind_param()` nor `bind_result()` will let you easily bind an *arbitrary* number of variables, which will make code even more bloated.

So, looking at all that mess I'd still suggest you to use either PDO or manually implemented placeholders, like [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) does.

Comment: I have actually found an easy solution to bind_param() and bind_result() which I use all the time. Well I guess it is about one line longer than what you would use with PDO, but hey, it yis what it yis.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example that works:

```
$query="SELECT service_ip,service_port FROM users WHERE username=? and password=?";
$conn=connection();

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user,$pass);
$ans=$stmt->execute();

$service_ip=false;
$service_port=false;
$stmt->bind_result($service_ip,$service_port);

$stmt->fetch();

mysqli_free_result($ans);
$stmt->close();
$conn -> close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the working code, however, the manual notes that you should call store_result for all queries that return a result and I don't see this called anywhere in your code.

Comment: i remember i learn that api few months ago, and the code i gave you is a working production code, i think you are just missing the fetch

Comment: The code I posted is sudo code for the binding only. I too have working production code, but the order of the calls I listed is of some issue on my production server. The manual is quite clear about calling store_result. Also, opening multiple statements won't work unless you call store_result.

Taken directly from the php manual:

You must call mysqli_stmt_store_result() for every query that successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN), and only if you want to buffer the complete result set by the client...

Answer (score 0):

Here is *proper* code:

```
$query="SELECT service_ip,service_port FROM users WHERE username=? and password=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($user,$pass));
$data = $stmt->fetch()/fetchAll()/fetchColumn(); 
// whoops! that's all

// ...in case you want to execute again
$stmt->execute(array($user2,$pass2));
$data = $stmt->fetch()/fetchAll()/fetchColumn();

// and again...
$stmt->execute(array($user3,$pass3));
$data = $stmt->fetch()/fetchAll()/fetchColumn();
```

Note that you already have all required data. Feel the power of [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: I'm sure that PDO is great but this code really doesn't answer the question at all.Your code fails totally to bind any parameters or any results.

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. It actually binds either parameters and results. That's the point that makes PDO indeed great.

Comment: Like I said, PDO shure is great but an answer using it does not answer the question in the slightest.

Comment: It is entirely up to you. I just corrected your wrong statement about lack of binding.

Comment: That's why I upvoted your comment because you were very correct about that and about PDO making things easier.